# Windows 7 x64 - Junctions

Tags: windows, junction

I've created a junction from a folder on the C: drive to a folder on a different drive. For some reason the data in the C folder is still being stored / written to the C drive folder, but also into the folder on the other drive.

Every other junction I've created have worked correctly.

(it's my iPhone backup folder)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike shortcuts, the files in junctions will always show the "fake" path like C:\JunctionFolder\Subfolder\Data even though in reality once you're in C:\JunctionFolder, you are really working in another drive.

- Doing a search for files on your C drive will find files in a junction  by their fake names C:\JunctionFolder\etc.).
- Also, selecting several or all **folders** in your C drive and opening properties will count the number and size of files in your junction target as well, thus showing more files and total disk usage than what your C drive really contains.

However, the pie chart showin the **properties of your drive partition** (C) is reliable (right-click C drive, properties) - it will only include data that is written for real. To test this, copy a big file in your junction, and check these properties again.

Answer (score 0):

If this were true, then that means you have two folders that are mirrored in real time.

Are you sure this is the case??

My guess is the junction is working correctly and the junction is working so transparently that it is fooling you.

You can confirm the junction is working correctly by simply looking at the junction under Explorer.  Right click and look for its target.